# How to populate a datagridview VB.Net

Tags: mysql, arrays, vb.net, datagridview, datasource

I have queried my MySql database and data is stored in a dataset named Search Events(I have checked this and it works)
However when i try to pass this data into a datagridview and then ultimately my array it doesn't seem to work :( The problem seems to be that no data is being passed from Search Events into Table
Any ideas??

```
 Dim Table As New DataGridView
    Table.DataSource = SearchEvents.Tables("Event ID")
    Dim EventID(Table.Rows.Count - 1) As String
    For i = 0 To 12
        EventID(i) = Table.Rows(0).Cells(i).Value
    Next
```

Comment: If the Content of `SearchEvents.Tables("Event ID")` is right (= it is a valid table with the columns/rows you expect) everything should be fine. Set a break point and find out what might be the problem (99% of chances of SearchEvents.Tables("Event ID") not containing what you think).

Comment: what you have checking rows/columns this code only check column only

Comment: If i create an actual datagrid and place it on the form the code runs fine, its just when i use a variable that it breaks

Comment: Also the query only ever returns 1 column

Answer (score 0):

'Try the following function

```
    Public Sub getuserlist()
    Dim con As New MySqlConnection(ConnectionString)

    Try
        If con.State <> ConnectionState.Open Then
            con.Open()
        End If

        Dim selecttaxinv = "SELECT * FROM user_tb WHERE  user_status = 'Active' ORDER BY date_registered DESC"
        Dim myCommand As New MySqlCommand(selecttaxinv, con)
        Dim dr As MySqlDataReader
        dr = myCommand.ExecuteReader()
       yourdatagridview.Rows.Clear()
        Dim b = 1
        While dr.Read()
            Dim fullname As String = dr("fname") & " " & dr("mname") & " " & dr("lname")

            Dim row As String() = New String() {dr("user_id"), b, fullname, dr("fname"), dr("date_registered")}
            yourdatagridview.Rows.Add(row) 'print list
            b += 1
        End While
        dr.Close()


        If con.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
            con.Close()
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)

    End Try

End Sub
```